# MassTransit library sending request to azure but it don't enter the queue

Tags: c#, azure, masstransit

I am using MassTransit with Azure Bus and Autofact, I'm working on my localhost.

**THE PROBLEM:** I have no errors in the application, the problem is that in azure shows me that I send the "request" both in the queue and in the bus (orange line in the image), but they don't enter in the queue, they stay in request. Is everything correct in my MassTransit and azure bus configuration? Am I forgetting something or doing something wrong?

[image]

In Azure my queue is called "live-schedule-update-consumer" my topic is called "contracts ~ livescheduleupdatedata" and I have the subscription to "live-schedule-update-consumer" I don't have nothing in  the queue just one message I create this manually.

My configuration for masstransit:

```
public static IContainer ConfigureContainer()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

        cfg.AddConsumer<TeamTimeManager>();

        cfg.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, conf) =>
        {
            var settings = new HostSettings
            {
                ServiceUri = new Uri(AzureUrl),
                TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateManagedIdentityTokenProvider()
            };
            
            conf.SubscriptionEndpoint<ILiveScheduleUpdateRequest>("Live-Schedule-Update-Consumer", e =>
            {
                e.ConfigureConsumer<TeamTimeManager>(context);
            });

            conf.ConfigureEndpoints(context);

            conf.Host(settings);
        });
    });

    return builder.Build();
}
```

When I send to Azure

```
var liveScheduleUpdateData = new LiveScheduleUpdateData();
liveScheduleUpdateData.job = job;
liveScheduleUpdateData.schedFound = schedFound;
liveScheduleUpdateData.punchType = punchType;
liveScheduleUpdateData.employee = employee;
liveScheduleUpdateData.request = request;
liveScheduleUpdateData.offset = offset;

var container = CreatorContainer.ConfigureContainer();
var bus = container.Resolve<IBusControl>();

bus.Publish<ILiveScheduleUpdateRequest>(liveScheduleUpdateData);
```

My interface

```
public interface ILiveScheduleUpdateRequest
{
    Job job { get; }
    LiveSchedule schedFound { get; }
    PunchAction punchType { get; }
    User employee { get; }
    PunchRequest request { get; }
    double offset { get; }
}
```

My class

```
public class LiveScheduleUpdateData 
{
    public Job job { get; set; }
    public LiveSchedule schedFound { get; set; }
    public PunchAction punchType { get; set; }
    public User employee { get; set; }
    public PunchRequest request { get; set; }
    public double offset { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Start the bus? There is a [full sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-AzureServiceBus/tree/master/src) using MassTransit with Azure Service Bus.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson I have already started the bus, this is why I am receiving the requests in azure, but it isn't registering in the queue. Thank you I will check the example

Answer (score 1):

You're using a SubscriptionEndpoint, which consumes directly from the topic without using a queue. If you want to consume from a queue, remove the block with the `SubscriptionEndpoint()` and `ConfigureEndpoints` will create the topic, queue, and subscription to forward messages from the topic to the queue.